# Wordpress Inserting posts in another custom table

Tags: wordpress

Can I Insert wordpress posts on a different table.

```
$wpdb->insert( 
'my_documents', 
array( 
    'p_id' => '6', 
    'post_id' => 123 
), 
array( 
    '%s', 
    '%d' 
) 
);
```

The above insertions works fine. I want to insert the full post into another table by clicking on a save button beside each post.
any idea suggestions or links will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use some of the predefined hooks for POST.

1. add_action( 'save_post', 'save_post_to_other_table', 10, 3 ); 
   **will work after the saving the post first time.**
2. add_action( 'post_updated', 'update_post_to_other_table', 10, 3 ); 
   **will work after the updating the post.**

Please try the following code :

```
function save_post_to_other_table( $post_id, $post, $update ) {

   $wpdb->insert( 
                    'my_documents', 
                    array('p_id' => '6','post_id' => $post_id), 
                    array('%s','%d')
                );
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_post_to_other_table', 10, 3 );
function update_post_to_other_table( $post_id, $post, $update ) {

   $wpdb->update( 
                    'my_documents', 
                    array('p_id' => '6','post_id' => $post_id), 
                    array( 'post_id' => $post_id ),
                    array('%s','%d')
                );
}
add_action( 'post_updated', 'update_post_to_other_table', 10, 3 );
```

Hope this will work for you. You can also go through the document for the hooks used above [Save POST](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) & [Update POST](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/post_updated)

Comment: Thank you. my main target is this post.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49416869/wordpress-save-posts-from-category-page-list-to-another-page-bookmark     Add a save button beside each post and click button to save that post to another table. Thanks in advance